# Adding values from SQL Server CE 3.5 database to listview

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

```
private void table_loader()
{
    SqlCeConnection ucon = new SqlCeConnection();
    ucon.ConnectionString = " Data Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\laser\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\dbtest\\dbtest\\ulist.sdf";
    ucon.Open();
    SqlCeCommand uce = new SqlCeCommand();
    SqlCeDataAdapter uced = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
    uced.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM plist", ucon);
    uced.Fill(ulistDataSet, "plist");
    DataTable dplist = ulistDataSet.Tables["plist"];
    for (int i = 0; i <dplist.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        DataRow drow = dplist.Rows[i];

            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["Process"].ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(lvi.Text);
            listView2.Items.Add(lvi);

    }

}
```

I used the above code to show the database (SQL Server CE 3.5) values in listview but the listview doesn't show anything! also the message box() shows the database values correctly one by one when loop executes, i think the problem must be in adding values to listview. wat's wrong with this code, can anyone explain pls?. sorry for my poor english!

thanks in advance,
Ulaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code

```
listView2.Items.Add(drow["Process"].ToString()); //Verify that column's name is Process
```

answer with foreach syntax

```
foreach(var row in dplist.Rows)
{
  listView2.Items.Add(row["Process"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell exactly as item adding code looks good.
You may try:
1. Add columns to your list view `(listView2.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);)`
2. Switch list view to details mode `listView2.View = View.Details;`

Take a look at sample from msdn - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.100).aspx